# Elastic Search Reindexing does not progress

Tags: elasticsearch

I use ES reindex to copy documents from the src index to the destination index. While doing that, I am running a few ingestion pipelines. The reindexing is so slow. Not even a single document was uploaded in 1 hour. I am running ES on my MacBook Pro 2022.

Here is the reindexing task details.

```
{
  "completed": false,
  "task": {
    "node": "zn7bFe98Qly-eEd_VrXAMQ",
    "id": 688,
    "type": "transport",
    "action": "indices:data/write/reindex",
    "status": {
      "total": 2461,
      "updated": 0,
      "created": 0,
      "deleted": 0,
      "batches": 1,
      "version_conflicts": 0,
      "noops": 0,
      "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
      },
      "throttled_millis": 0,
      "requests_per_second": 1,
      "throttled_until_millis": 0
    },
    "description": "reindex from [source_index] to [destination_index]",
    "start_time_in_millis": 1681734787348,
    "running_time_in_nanos": 1800085540069,
    "cancellable": true,
    "cancelled": false,
    "headers": {}
  }
}
```

You can see out of  2461; nothing was created.

I am using `requests_per_second=1`

And Ingest pipeline is

```
{
  "document-pipeline": {
    "description": "abc",
    "on_failure": [
      {
        "set": {
          "description": "Index document to 'failed-<index>'",
          "field": "_index",
          "value": "failed-{{{_index}}}"
        }
      },
      {
        "set": {
          "description": "Sazzad pycharm ingestion failed error message",
          "field": "ingest.failure",
          "value": "{{_ingest.on_failure_message}}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "processors": [
      {
        "inference": {
          "model_id": "sentence-transformers__paraphrase-mpnet-base-v2",
          "target_field": "name_embedding",
          "field_map": {
            "name": "text_field"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "inference": {
          "model_id": "sentence-transformers__paraphrase-mpnet-base-v2",
          "target_field": "description_embedding",
          "field_map": {
            "description": "text_field"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "inference": {
          "model_id": "sentence-transformers__paraphrase-mpnet-base-v2",
          "target_field": "custom_field1_embedding",
          "field_map": {
            "custom_field1": "text_field"
          }
        }
      }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any clue? What is the problem under the hood?

Edit 2 - Output of `GET _cat/tasks/?v&actions=*reindex&detailed`

```
`action                     task_id                     parent_task_id type      start_time    timestamp running_time ip         node         description
indices:data/write/reindex zn7bFe98Qly-eEd_VrXAMQ:1250 -              transport 1681738821297 13:40:21  3.2m         172.19.0.2 4cdda1de1ed0 reindex from [source] to [destination]
```

Edit 3 - Output of `GET _nodes/hot_threads`

```
::: {4cdda1de1ed0}{zn7bFe98Qly-eEd_VrXAMQ}{nlHIUMF4SnGX8h_vrEYVYA}{4cdda1de1ed0}{172.19.0.2}{172.19.0.2:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.7.0}{ml.max_jvm_size=4118806528, ml.allocated_processors=4, ml.machine_memory=8233017344, xpack.installed=true, ml.allocated_processors_double=4.0}
   Hot threads at 2023-04-17T14:08:51.922Z, interval=500ms, busiestThreads=3, ignoreIdleThreads=true:
   
    0.6% [cpu=0.6%, idle=99.4%] (500ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[4cdda1de1ed0][transport_worker][T#4]'
     3/10 snapshots sharing following 3 elements
       io.netty.common@4.1.86.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
       io.netty.common@4.1.86.Final/io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
       java.base@19.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

Edit 4: output of `GET /_nodes/stats?pretty&filter_path=**.ingest.pipelines`

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "zn7bFe98Qly-eEd_VrXAMQ": {
      "ingest": {
        "pipelines": {
          "recipe-name_description_custom_steps_custom_ingredients_custom_tags-field-embeddings-pipeline": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "recipe-custom_steps-field-embeddings-pipeline": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "recipe-description-field-embeddings-pipeline": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "recipe--field-embeddings-pipeline": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 1000,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 1000,
                    "time_in_millis": 288844826,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 471,
                    "time_in_millis": 645430266,
                    "current": 529,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 471,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "recipe-name-field-embeddings-pipeline": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "recipe-custom_ingredients-field-embeddings-pipeline": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "synthetics-browser.screenshot-0.11.8": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "pipeline:synthetics-browser.screenshot@custom": {
                  "type": "pipeline",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          ".fleet_final_pipeline-1": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "date:truncate-subseconds-event-ingested": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "remove": {
                  "type": "remove",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "set_security_user": {
                  "type": "set_security_user",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "script:agent-id-status": {
                  "type": "script",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "remove": {
                  "type": "remove",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "synthetics-icmp-0.11.8": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "pipeline:synthetics-icmp@custom": {
                  "type": "pipeline",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "synthetics-http-0.11.8": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "pipeline:synthetics-http@custom": {
                  "type": "pipeline",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "recipe-name_description_custom_steps_custom_ingredients-field-embeddings-pipeline": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "inference": {
                  "type": "inference",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "synthetics-browser.network-0.11.8": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "pipeline:synthetics-browser.network@custom": {
                  "type": "pipeline",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "synthetics-browser-0.11.8": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "pipeline:synthetics-browser@custom": {
                  "type": "pipeline",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "synthetics-tcp-0.11.8": {
            "count": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "failed": 0,
            "processors": [
              {
                "pipeline:synthetics-tcp@custom": {
                  "type": "pipeline",
                  "stats": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "failed": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the ingest pipeline the documents have to go through?

Comment: @val , Hey, good to see you back. updated the question

Comment: Have you checked your `failed-index` to make sure that the documents don't end up there? because it clearly looks like it if all documents have been processed but your destination index is empty

Comment: Yes, Failed one is not created yet.

Comment: We can also see `completed": false` which means the task is still running

Comment: Can you provide what you get from `GET _cat/tasks/?v&actions=*reindex&detailed` ?

Comment: Yes It was running for more than an hour. But not a single document was created. `"created": 0`

Comment: Can you add the output to your question, it'll be more legible

Comment: Can you also provide the result you get from `GET _nodes/hot_threads`?

Comment: Sure, Updated the question with output

Comment: Ok that one yields nothing interesting. What about `GET /_nodes/stats?pretty&filter_path=**.ingest.pipelines`?

Comment: updated the question with output

Comment: What's the real name of your ingest pipeline? It's not `document-pipeline`. Besides, none of the pipelines show `count > 0`, so there must be some weirder issue going on

Comment: Sorry, last time, I did not give the real name for the pipeline and index. It was a dummy name before. But the outputs are correct, I guarantee

Comment: this is the pipeline name `recipe-name_description_custom_steps_custom_ingredients_custom_tags-field-embeddings-pipeline`

Comment: Nothing is currently going through `name_description_custom_steps_custom_ingredients_custom_tags-field-embeddings-pipeline` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `recipe--field-embeddings-pipeline` you can see that there are 1000 documents in the pipeline:

- all 1000 have gone through the first inference processor
- 529 are currently going through the second inference processor
- 471 are currently going through the third inference processor

This means that it is working, but it takes time, probably because `requests_per_second=1` makes it really slow.

So nothing wrong, just slow. You can tune and follow the progress via `GET /_nodes/stats?pretty&filter_path=**.ingest.pipelines` to see if you can get it to go faster.

Comment: In the last change, I updated `requests_per_second = 150` now, After your suggestion.
I am using `requests_per_second = 300`.

I will accept your answer once my reindexing is successful :) Hope that's okay

Comment: Great, let's see what unfolds ;-)

Comment: It is still running :D, But as your answer helps me track the progress, I accept it. :)